# Awesome-wm notifications to bottom-right

Tags: notifications, position, awesome-wm

I'm looking for a way to move all desktop notifications from top-right to bottom-right but all I can find googling around is this page https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/core_components/naughty.notification.html which seems to explain how to do it from a programmers point of view and not from the WM config point of view.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which seems to explain how to do it from a programmers point of view and not from the WM config point of view. Any pointers?

The config is actually "real" code. So the documentation *is* for the config (or any module/extension).

As for the question itself. The best way to do it with a awesome git-master (which is the link you provided) is to modify the rules (`ruled.notification` section of the git-master version of `rc.lua`) and set the `position` property.

```lua
-- Correct way for awesome >= v4.4/git-master.
--
-- IF YOU HAVE A RECENT RC.LUA THIS SECTION IS ALREADY THERE,
-- ELSE, ADD IT.
--
-- WARNING: WILL **NOT** WORK IN < v4.4/git-master
ruled.notification.connect_signal('request::rules', function()
    -- All notifications will match this rule.
    ruled.notification.append_rule {
        rule       = { },
        properties = {
            screen           = awful.screen.preferred,
            implicit_timeout = 5,
            position         = "bottom_right", -- <<<<< ADD THIS
        }
    }
end)
```

If you are on version 3.4 to 4.3, the only way to set it is using the "notification presets"

```lua
-- OLD WAY, DEPRECATED in git-master/v4.4+
for _, preset in pairs(naughty.config.presets) do
    preset.position = "bottom_right"
end
```